# Get parse tree of a sentence using OpenNLP. Getting stuck with example.

Tags: java, parsing, intellij-idea, nlp, opennlp

OpenNLP is an Apache project on Natural Language Processing. One of the aims of an NLP program is to parse a sentence giving a tree of its grammatical structure. For example, the sentence "The sky is blue." might be parsed as

```
      S
     / \
   NP   VP
  / \    | \
The sky is blue.
```

where `S` is Sentence, `NP` is Noun-phrase, and `VP` is Verb-phrase. Equivalently the above tree can be written down as a parenthesized string like this: `S(NP(The sky) VP(is blue.))`

I am trying to be able to get the parenthesized strings from sentences using OpenNLP, but I can't get the example code to work.

In particular, I am following along [the last part of this tutorial](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/05/opennlp-tutorial/#parser) and my code gets stuck at initializing `ParserModel`.

I have downloaded the appropriate binaries from [here](http://opennlp.apache.org/cgi-bin/download.cgi) and added `opennlp-tools-1.5.3.jar` (which includes classes for all of the following objects) as a library to my IntelliJ project. Also, I moved `en-parser-chunking.bin` to my "user.dir."

The following is the code which should give me a parse tree, but it runs indefinitely at creating the `ParserModel` object.

```
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("en-parser-chunking.bin");
    ParserModel model = new ParserModel(is);
    Parser parser = ParserFactory.create(model);
    String sentence = "The sky is blue.";
    Parse topParses[] = ParserTool.parseLine(sentence, parser, 1);
    for (Parse p : topParses)
        p.show();
    is.close();
```

It's my first day of working with OpenNLP, but I can't even get this simple example to work.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void Parse() throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
    // http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/opennlp/index.php?title=Parser#Training_Tool
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("en-parser-chunking.bin");

    ParserModel model = new ParserModel(is);

    Parser parser = ParserFactory.create(model);

    String sentence = "Programcreek is a very huge and useful website.";
    Parse topParses[] = ParserTool.parseLine(sentence, parser, 1);

    for (Parse p : topParses)
        p.show();

    is.close();

    /*
     * (TOP (S (NP (NN Programcreek) ) (VP (VBZ is) (NP (DT a) (ADJP (RB
     * very) (JJ huge) (CC and) (JJ useful) ) ) ) (. website.) ) )
     */
}
```

try this

Comment: if you can add source link please, it will be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your model might be damaged. Try downloading it again and use that one. If that doesn't help, call `kill -QUIT <pid>` (under Linux) to get a stacktrace when the process hangs, or use a debugger.

Comment: Actually somebody deleted my answer to this question. I said "The program does get stuck at creating the ParserModel, but only for about 30 seconds. For some reason I assumed that there is no way that it would take more than a few seconds. However anticlimactic it is, I should have just waited 30 seconds. ParserModel looks at a file which is 36 Mbs so the performance is reasonable." Do you still think the model might be damaged?

Comment: @ijkilchenko I am in the same situation, it really takes a lot of time to initiate the ParseModel, but for what I know there is no way to undergo this... even the official guide states "Loading the big parser model can take several seconds, be patient."
The only suggestion is to load it in a static way for you whole application, also I would suggest to use `getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("en-parser-chunking.bin")`

Comment: @5agado, I have put together a web application which is running on an Amazon server and I put the loading of the parser into the Servlet's init() function. Fortunately, it only needs to load once per running of the program (I was afraid that it might have to reload the parser per user's session). It does take 30 seconds, but only once which is very tolerable. Let me know if I can help you more.